# Do Kafka consumers spin on poll() or are they woken up by a broadcast/signal from the broker?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

If I `poll()` from a `consumer` in a `while True:` statement, I see that `poll()` is blocking. If the consumer is up to date with messages from the topic (`offset = OFFSET_END`) how is the consumer conducting it's blocking `poll()`?

Does the consumer default adhere to a pub/sub mentality in which it sleeps and waits for a publish and a broadcast/signal from the broker?

Or is the consumer constantly spinning itself checking the topic?

I'm using the confluent python client, if that matters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kafka consumers are basically long poll loops, driven (asynchronously) by the user thread calling poll().

the whole protocol is request-response, and entirely client driven. there is no form of broker-initiated "push".

fetch.max.wait.ms controls how long any single broker will wait before responding (if no data), while blocking of the user thread is controlled by argument to poll()

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right its while a true condition that waits to consume the message till waiting timeout time.
If it receives a message it will return immediately otherwise it will await to passed timeout and return an empty record.

Kafka Broker use the below parameter to control message to send to Consumer

1. **fetch.min.bytes:** The broker will wait for this amount of data to fill BEFORE it sends the response to the consumer client.
2. **fetch.wait.max.ms**: The broker will wait for this amount of time BEFORE sending a response to the consumer client unless it has enough data to fill the response (fetch.message.max.bytes)

There is a possibility to take a long time to call the next poll() due to the processing of consumed messages. max.poll.interval.ms prevent not to process take so much time and call the next poll within max.poll.interval.ms otherwise consumer leaves the group and trigger rebalance.
You can get more detail about this [here](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)

> 1. **max.poll.interval.ms:** By increasing the interval between expected polls, you can give the consumer more time to handle a batch of
>    records returned from poll(long). The drawback is that increasing this
>    value may delay a group rebalance since the consumer will only join
>    the rebalance inside the call to poll. You can use this setting to
>    bound the time to finish a rebalance, but you risk slower progress if
>    the consumer cannot actually call poll often enough.
> 2. **max.poll.records:** Use this setting to limit the total records returned from a single call to a poll. This can make it easier to
>    predict the maximum that must be handled within each poll interval. By
>    tuning this value, you may be able to reduce the poll interval, which
>    will reduce the impact of group rebalancing.

Comment: max.poll.interval.ms is not how long poll takes to return, its how long a user is allowed to take between subsequent calls to poll.

Comment: Seems my wording confused you. I did updated little bit to clarify